# I can't boot into recovery on my C6603

Tags: recovery-mode, sony-xperia-z

So Basically I put a recovery into my sony xperia z and i tried flashing an unofficial cyanogenmod 12. But afterwards the phone could not boot up to recovery due to the way i get into the recovery. Usually, the sony boot up sign would show up then i would press the volume up or volume down button to get to the recovery. But the phone can't even boot up now. What do i do?

Comment: Can you go into the Bootloader? If yes, you can flash the ROM and Recovery and save your device.

Comment: Besides, are you certain it is charged enough?

Comment: After flashing a custom ROM you have to press the volume key when the LED lights up (purple, if I remember correctly), not when the logo appears.